# Switch statement doesn't gives out the cases I want

Tags: php, regex, mysqli

I have 2 problems here. First, I don't know how to use `preg_match` for filtering out digits and special characters, only letter and a & should be allowed to be contained.

Also, this script doesn't work how it should. I mean it works, but the `switch` statement only delivers the last string that contains an error, and if I put it inside the `foreach`, it gives out 1 time the first error and 3 times the second error.

What am I doing wrong? Please help me!

```
<?php
// test variables
$act1 = "SUBSCRIBEa";
$act2 = "SUBSCRIBEb";
$act3 = "SUBSCRIBE";
$act4 = "SUBSCRIBE";

// set error false as default
$error = "false";

// check if variables are ready for use
if(!empty($act1) && !empty($act2) && !empty($act3) && !empty($act4)) {
$acts = [$act1, $act2, $act3, $act4];

// check the acts for lenght, numbers and special characters
// add all of the acts to an array to loop over
foreach($acts as $key => $value) {

    if($key < 9) {
        $errorKey = "0{$key}";
    } else {
        $errorKey = $key;
    }

    // check the lenght
    if(strlen($value) > 15) {
        $error = "true";
        $errorNumber = $errorKey;
    }

    /* check for numbers and special characters
    if(!preg_match('/[^a-z&A-Z]/', $value)){
        $error = "true";
        $errorNumber = $error_{$errorKey};
    }
*/

// declare a whitelist of things that should not produce an error
$whiteList = [
    'SUBSCRIBE',
    'SUB & LIKE',
    'LIKE & COMMENT',
    'DISLIKE',
    'COMMENT',
    'LIKE',
    'FOLLOW',
];

    // check if value from act is in the whitelist declared above, if its not, set `$error` to true and set `$error_*` (with key) to "true" as well.
    if(!in_array($value, $whiteList)) {
        $error = "true";
        $errorNumber = $errorKey;
    }   

}
}
// deliver the error message
switch($errorNumber){
    case 00:
        echo "Something went wrong here 1 :o";
        break;
    case 01:    
        echo "Something went wrong here 2 :o";
        break;
    case 02:
        echo "Something went wrong here 3 :o";
        break;
    case 03:
        echo "Something went wrong here 4 :o";
        break;
}
?>
```

Comment: try quoting the numbers in the `case` statements, they are strings.

Comment: Use strings instead: `case '02':` etc.

Comment: I removed them, they had quotes before, but still not such a mess

Comment: echo $errorKey. What is it? Also, yo should have a default

Comment: ? what do you mean

Comment: I removed the default too

Comment: now I added strings again but it still puts out only the last error number

Comment: It doesn't really matter when you use numbers below 8 with a leading zero, but `01` is actually octal. That means that `012` won't be integer 12.  Proof: https://3v4l.org/Ms85B

Comment: Well, you should ALWAYS have a default incase something isn't caught. Switches are for there WILL be one of these choices occurring

Comment: But you use a string to signify.

Comment: Also, why not store the accounts in an array and check if array count is not less than 4? That if statement looks like hell. You're converting it to an array anyway afterwards. Messy code and a lack of clear understanding on what you're trying to do will limit the answers you get.

Comment: Hello again :) Give me a few moments and I will post an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following code, I commented as much as I could to try to show you what I did to (possibly) fix your issue.

```
<?php
    // test variables
    $act1 = "SUBSCRIBEa";
    $act2 = "SUBSCRIBEb";
    $act3 = "SUBSCRIBE";
    $act4 = "SUBSCRIBE";

    // set error false as default
    $error = false;

    // check if variables are ready for use, if they are, add them to `$acts` array
    // I do each check as a seperate line, as it looks cleaner than 1 long if statement.
    $acts = [];
    if(!empty($act1)) $acts[] = $act1;
    if(!empty($act2)) $acts[] = $act2;
    if(!empty($act3)) $acts[] = $act3;
    if(!empty($act4)) $acts[] = $act4;

    // declare a whitelist (outside of loop) of things that should not produce an error
    $whiteList = [
        'SUBSCRIBE',
        'SUB & LIKE',
        'LIKE & COMMENT',
        'DISLIKE',
        'COMMENT',
        'LIKE',
        'FOLLOW',
    ];

    //create an empty array to hold errors
    $errors = [];

    // check the acts for lenght, numbers and special characters
    // add all of the acts to an array to loop over
    foreach($acts as $key => $value) {

        //1 line ternary is cleaner than if/else statetmnt
        $errorKey = $key < 9? "0{$key}" : $key;

        //each row by default has no error
        $hasError = 0;

        // check the lenght
        //use regex to check if a string only contains letters.
        // check if value from act is in the whitelist declared above, if its not, set `$error` to true and set `$error_*` (with key) to "true" as well.
        // make sure you use `||` (or) here, not `&&` (and), otherwise this statement will not work properly. If it's `||` only 1 thing has to be wrong, if it's `&&` then all of them have to be wrong.
        if(strlen($value) > 15 || preg_match('/[^A-Za-z &]/', $value) || !in_array($value, $whiteList)) {
            $error = true;

            //if error occurs, set `$hasError` to 1, to later insert errorKey into array.
            $hasError = 1;
        }

        //
        if($hasError) {
            //store error in array, to loop through later
            $errors[] = $errorKey;
        }

    }

    // deliver the error message
    //Check if $error has been set to true at any point
    if($error) {
        //loop through error array, echo error message if $errorNumber matches.
        //at this point we KNOW there was an error at some point, no need to use a switch really
        foreach($errors as $errorNumber) {
            echo "Something went wrong here $errorNumber :o";
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: it doesn't display me anything now :o, no error message

Comment: Well, which of your test cases is supposed to error out?

Comment: @IlyaDynin Figured it out, fixed.

Comment: MAN YOU ARE AMAZING, I hope you can help me out with my future questions! I seriously have get a book from my library, to learn all that :o

Comment: @IlyaDynin I'm on here basically every day so I'll probably be around :)

Comment: There is another little problem here :( The Whitelist doesn't work with words that contain a space, also the preg_match should allow & character :( I hope you can help a last time today

Comment: @IlyaDynin Actually it should work with words with a space. I think it's the preg_match messing up in both cases. Give me a moment

Comment: @IlyaDynin Just have to add those 2 symbols to the preg_match and it should be okay. Updated my code